# Set color attribute of selected vertices/vertex group

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to store different colors per vertex group in an attribute map.
All assigned verts in vertex group1 = green
All assigned verts in vertex group2 = blue.

On my test cube all top vertices are selected and in a vertex group called selection and should be colored green.
Best I could come up with is with a separate geometry node,but this makes me lose the edges between top and bottom of the cube.
And also is limited to selection and inverted selection instead of multiple vertex groups.
[image]

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a switch or a mix node:

[image]

...

Comment: That works, how do I introduce a third or fourth color based on a vertex group selection?(assuming there are no overlapping vertex groups)

Comment: @Tortenrandband by making a tree of switches.

Comment: That works (but feels clumsy compared to python api, but I'm still getting used to geo nodes and I really like the fast viewport preview of GN)

Comment: @Tortenrandband In Blender 4 you can use a repeat zone, but you still need to somehow provide the names of vertex groups, so if there's just a few of them, multiple switches seem like the easiest solution.